Splitting single cells with multiple separator
I have a data set that includes bunch of single cells that has multiple words with separator ";". Is there a way to separate this single cell into 3 different cells?

I am trying to automate this process so it is better to do it without excel's text-to-column function

=TEXTSPLIT() does that.

If you are using an older version of Excel, like Office 2010 you can use;
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2;";";REPT(" ";LEN($A2)));(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*LEN($A2)+1;LEN($A2)))

Enter the formula and drag right. Depending on your locale settings you may need to change ";" with ","

Try this code in VBA.
This code assumes that the data necessary to split is in the column "A" and outputs the values to the right of the cell with the data.
Option Explicit
' This function will calculate how much strings you will need to split. This is necessary to fill in correct amount of headers 
Function CountOfChar(str As String, character As String) As Integer
      CountOfChar = UBound(Split(str, character))
End Function

' This function will find the last row of your data in the "A" column
Public Function FindLastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    FindLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End Function

Sub SplitSingleCell()
 'Defining worksheet and lastRow variables
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Dim lastRow As Long
 
 'Finding the last row in the worksheet
 lastRow = FindLastRow(ws)
 
 'Defining variables necessary for iteration
 Dim startingRow As Long
 Dim count As Long
 Dim Arr As Variant
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long

 'Using a for loop we iterate through row starting from the second row (assuming you have headers)
 
 For startingRow = 2 To lastRow
    count = CountOfChar(Cells(startingRow, 1), ";") 'Counting how much strings you will have to split from each cell
    If count > 2 Then 'If there are more than 2 cells to split 
        For i = 1 To count + 1 'We iterate through Cells starting from "B1" 
        Cells(1, i + 1) = "Name " & i 'We input values "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", etc. to the necessary header cells, just like in OPs example
        Next i
    End If
    Arr = Split(Cells(startingRow, 1), ";") 'Next we split the cell values and put them into an array
        For j = 1 To UBound(Arr) + 1 'We iterate through the array
            Cells(startingRow, j + 1) = Arr(j - 1) 'And finally we input the values from the array into the necessary
        Next j
 Next startingRow

End Sub


If you are on Microsoft-365 then could use TEXTSPLIT()-
=TEXTSPLIT(A2,";")

For Excel-2013 and later could use FILTERXML().
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[" & COLUMN(A$1) &"]")



Your FILTERXML would need dragging across so the COLUMN(A$1) increases as you drag.  Maybe use =TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))

@DarrenBartrup-Cook This will work only to O365. For older version need it to drag manually.

I wasn't sure.  Been so long since I've used anything other than 365.

So, just using left(), mid(), right(), trim() and find() which works for all versions of Excel:

In cell C1:
TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1,1)-1))

In cell D1:
TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,1)+1,FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1,1)+1)-FIND(";",A1,1)-1))

And in cell E1:
TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1,1)+1)))

Take them apart to see what does what.
